# SQL Failover Cluster - 'SQL Server' service terminating because of 'fatal exception c06d007e'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have an SQL Failover cluster (2016) with 2 VMs. The 'SQL Server' service was down when seen from 'Failover Cluster Manager'. On checking the Event Viewer logs, the SQL Server showed below error.

[Event Viewer log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7acQx.png)

Also, few files (SqlServerSpatial140.dll, SqlServerSpatial130.dll and SqlServerManager13.msc) were missing in C:\Windows\System32 path.

Running SQL Server Repair also failed. Has anyone faced such issue with the SQL Failover Cluster? Need help in addressing this problem.

Comment: What does the `ERRORLOG` contain just prior to the shutdown?

Comment: `0xc06d007e` translates to facility code of visual c++, and error code module not found. If this is consistently occurring, then the next step would be reproduce the item while obtaining a procmon so that you could find the module not found and replace it. If repair isn't working that could be due to unrelated reasons, most generally installer cache issues.

Comment: Is this happening regardless of which node you're trying to run the service on?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener,
The ERRORLOG before shutdown showed:
Short Stack Dump
00007FF87C704078 Module (KERNELBASE+0000000000034078)
...
00007FF87D0284D4 Module (KERNEL32+00000000000084D4)
00007FF87F5DE851 Module (ntd11+000000000006£851)
Stack Signature for the dump 13 0x0000000004869C5
External dump process return code 0x20000003.
Error - Failed to create dump file.

Comment: @MelvinLusk, yes happening on both the nodes when starting the SQL Service.